# Android Widget calling enabled not when expected

Tags: android, widget

I am trying to find a way to check the number of contacts the user has set when the user adds my widget to the homescreen. if not then open my custom contact picker.

When I hold on the homescreen, choose widgets, hold the widget icon, my program calls onEnabled

```
public void onEnabled(Context context) 
{
        Log.i(TAG,"in onEnabled");
        SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("settings_category", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(sharedPrefs.getInt("numContacts", 0) == 0)
        {
            Intent con_intent = new Intent(context, ContactPrefActivity.class);
            con_intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(con_intent);
            Toast.makeText(context, "No Contacts Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } 
}
```

I want it to call when the widget is placed somewhere on the homescreen.

1. Is 'onEnabled()' the right method? If it is, what am I doing wrong?
2. If not then, which method is called when the widget is placed on the screen?

Comment: 1- yes, onEnabled() is the right method which is called when the widget is put on the home screen for the very first time, then onUpdate() is the method invoked when update occurres

Comment: Its called when first placed on the launcher and depending on the launcher implementation its also called when the launcher starts and when the phone first boots.